# Android Maven ClassNotFound

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 12.1 and everything runs perfectly when I try to build and install.  When I try to build and install the app via Maven I get the following error:

```
04-10 21:28:03.044: WARN/dalvikvm(12727): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/moneydesktop/finance/shared/activity/BaseActivity; (105)
04-10 21:28:03.044: WARN/dalvikvm(12727): Link of class 'Lcom/moneydesktop/finance/shared/activity/BaseActivity;' failed
04-10 21:28:03.044: WARN/dalvikvm(12727): VFY: unable to resolve static field 5288 (sInForeground) in Lcom/moneydesktop/finance/shared/activity/BaseActivity;
04-10 21:28:03.044: INFO/dalvikvm(12727): Could not find method com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent.onError, referenced from method com.moneydesktop.finance.exception.CustomExceptionHandler.uncaughtException
04-10 21:28:03.044: WARN/dalvikvm(12727): VFY: unable to resolve static method 8300: Lcom/flurry/android/FlurryAgent;.onError (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
04-10 21:28:03.104: INFO/greenDAO(12727): Creating tables for schema version 1
04-10 21:28:03.285: WARN/dalvikvm(12727): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/moneydesktop/finance/shared/activity/BaseActivity; (105)
04-10 21:28:03.285: WARN/dalvikvm(12727): Link of class 'Lcom/moneydesktop/finance/shared/activity/BaseActivity;' failed
04-10 21:28:03.285: WARN/dalvikvm(12727): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/moneydesktop/finance/SplashActivity; (1158)
04-10 21:28:03.285: WARN/dalvikvm(12727): Link of class 'Lcom/moneydesktop/finance/SplashActivity;' failed
04-10 21:28:03.285: WARN/dalvikvm(12727): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cf0930)
04-10 21:28:03.285: ERROR/CustomExceptionHandler(12727): Error
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.moneydesktop.finance/com.moneydesktop.finance.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.moneydesktop.finance.SplashActivity" on path: /data/app/com.moneydesktop.finance-1.apk
```

**My pom.xml looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <version>1.0</version>
    <groupId>com.moneydesktop.finance</groupId>
    <artifactId>moneymobile</artifactId>
    <name>MoneyMobile</name>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <android.version>4.1.1.4</android.version>
        <android.platform>16</android.platform>

        <android-maven.version>3.5.3</android-maven.version>
        <maven-compiler.version>3.1</maven-compiler.version>

        <nineoldandroids.version>2.4.0</nineoldandroids.version>
        <viewpageindicator.version>2.4.1</viewpageindicator.version>
        <timessquare.version>1.0.3</timessquare.version>
        <menudrawer.version>2.0.2</menudrawer.version>
        <greendao.version>1.3.1</greendao.version>
        <eventbus.version>2.0.2</eventbus.version>
        <jackson.version>2.1.4</jackson.version>
        <lang.version>2.6</lang.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${android.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nineoldandroids</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>${nineoldandroids.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.viewpagerindicator</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>${viewpageindicator.version}</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-times-square</artifactId>
            <version>${timessquare.version}</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.simonvt</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-menudrawer</artifactId>
            <version>${menudrawer.version}</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.greenrobot</groupId>
            <artifactId>greendao</artifactId>
            <version>${greendao.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.greenrobot</groupId>
            <artifactId>eventbus</artifactId>
            <version>${eventbus.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.lang</artifactId>
            <version>${lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.saulpower.communication</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.saulpower.fayeclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.flurry</groupId>
            <artifactId>FlurryAgent</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/FlurryAgent.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.devsmart</groupId>
            <artifactId>DevsMart</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/devsmartlib.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>r12</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/android-support-v4-r12.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android-maven.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdk>
                            <platform>${android.platform}</platform>
                        </sdk>
                        <sign>
                            <debug>auto</debug>
                        </sign>
                        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    </configuration>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <manifest>
                        <debuggable>true</debuggable>
                    </manifest>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>manifestUpdate</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest-update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>alignApk</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>zipalign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <configLocation>../checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>checkstyle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

To run the maven build and install I use the following command:

```
mvn clean package install android:deploy android:run -Dandroid.device=usb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of flurry, devsmart and support-v4 should be compile (the default) they need to be included in your final build.

support-v4 is available in central, but you may need to install the other two to your local repository.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```